# Do I have to leave this edit in place?

Tags: discussion

An answer of mine that is a few years old was edited recently:

https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/7496/revisions

I don't think my answer was "too personal" and I liked it the way it was. So have several dozen other people. Also, I could be wrong, but I think this edit pushed it into "community wiki" status, which means I don't get any rep when people up-vote my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer became CW because the question was made so after it was posted.  I am not sure why all the answers weren't automatically marked at the time since that's how I understand the process, I will correct that.  **Update:** Due to a question merge!

I do believe the edit was inappropriate as well.  Editing for style preference is discouraged since the post still has your name on it.  Plus it removed information.